# Kubectl delete but ignore ones with error

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, kubectl

I have a list of namespaces and i want to delete them but some of them are giving error and i want to skip that ones and continue other deletions. How can i do that?

```
kubectl delete services,deployments -n ${namespace} --all  --grace-period=10
```

Comment: you described issue looks pretty weird. Not possible to understand if you have same error (no route to host.) each time, or during only chosen namespaces deletion? Can you  increase  logs verbosity and provide erorrs you receive (by editing initial post). [Kubectl output verbosity and debugging](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#kubectl-output-verbosity-and-debugging)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can try using `--ignore-not-found=true` flag in command

```
kubectl delete deployments --ignore-not-found=true -n ${namespace} --all  --grace-period=10
```

Comment: my namespace getting error like this: Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp ...: getsockopt: no route to host.   and my jenkinsjob getting stuck in there, after that namespace it wont continue deleting ohter ones.

Comment: You want to delete the namespace or deployments? Because you are mentioning namespace so I am confused?

Comment: my mistake. In my test environment there are more than one namespaces. Actually i'm deleting deployments and services in namespaces but in this particular namespace i'm getting error and code in my question is in for loop.

Comment: btw when i look at kubectl get pods --all-namespaces that namespace does not seem to running

Comment: first list namespace using ```kubectl get ns``` and delete the namespace which you want to delete using ```kubectl delete ns <yournaespacename>``` and once you delete the namespace it will delete all the pod,deployment service etc from that namespace

Comment: @meursault try what I have explain in my above comment and let me know.!!

Comment: I tried to delete it and i'm getting this Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp ...: getsockopt: no route to host

Comment: can you rewrite your question,  as per it you still want to delete namespaces...Add plz on your edit question everything you found, any logs that can help community. Then follow @Dashrath Mundkar, show us your errors. Then community will easily help you